# Creating pdf document in memory

Tags: java, pdf-generation, pdfbox

I need to create PDF document in Memory I am using pdfbox.

Here is my code but it creates document on disk.

```
public PDDocument generatePDF(String name, String v1, String v2, String v3, String v4) {
        PDPageContentStream contentStream = null;
        PDDocument document = null;
        try {
            document = new PDDocument();
            PDPage page = new PDPage();
            document.addPage(page);
            contentStream = new PDPageContentStream(document, page);


            fillDataInPDF(...);
            corpPDF(page);
        } catch (IOException err) {
            LOG.error("Error occured .");
        } finally {
            if (contentStream != null) {
                try {
                    contentStream.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    LOG.error("Error occured .");
                }
            }
        }
        return document;
    }
```

Comment: Ok. I approve of your desire to create it in memory. Have you actually done that or did something not work?

Comment: I have created on disk, don't know how to proceed for in memory.

Comment: There's nothing in your code sample that would suggest that it was created on disc.

Comment: You can save your PDF into a `ByteArrayOutputStream` and that one can be converted to a byte array. Maybe that is what you wanted?

Comment: @singhal please click the green checkmark on the answer if it is what you needed, or post a comment if you need further / different help in this matter.

Answer (score 2):

As @M.Prokhorov already remarked in a comment to your question, *there's nothing in your code sample that would suggest that it was created on disc.* In particular the `PDDocument` constructor you use here

```
document = new PDDocument();
```

is a short form of

```
document = new PDDocument(MemoryUsageSetting.setupMainMemoryOnly());
```

and *setups buffering memory usage to only use main-memory (no temporary file) which is not restricted in size.*

Thus, unless there is something hidden in `fillDataInPDF` or `corpPDF` that writes to a file, your method creates a PDF object model purely in memory.

As I don't suppose you would have hidden such an obvious file write, your claim that the document is created on disk most likely implies that **a caller of your method `generatePDF` serializes that model as PDF file to disk,** e.g. like this

```
PDDocument doc = generatePDF(name, v1, v2, v3, v4);
doc.save("SOME_FILE_PATH_ON_DISC");
```

As @TilmanHausherr pointed out *you can save your PDF into a `ByteArrayOutputStream` and that one can be converted to a byte array,* e.g. instead of the above you should use

```
PDDocument doc = generatePDF(name, v1, v2, v3, v4);
ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
doc.save(baos);
byte[] pdfBytes = baos.toByteArray();
```

and so keep also the serialized PDF file in memory.

Answer (score 1):

**I was able to create the PDF in memory and open in new tab using PDFBox**. 
I had written this Resource handler method. Just write below code.

```
HttpServletResponse response = PortalUtil.getHttpServletResponse(resourceResponse);

ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
PDDocument doc = new PDDocument();

PDPage page = new PDPage();
doc.addPage(page);

PDPageContentStream contentStream = new PDPageContentStream(doc, page);

// Your logic for adding content in PDF goes here

contentStream.close();

doc.save(baos);

response.setHeader("Expires", "0"); 
response.setHeader("Cache-Control", "must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0"); 
response.setHeader("Pragma", "public");
response.setContentType("application/pdf"); 
response.setContentLength(baos.size()); 
ServletOutputStream out = response.getOutputStream(); 
baos.writeTo(out); 
out.flush();
```